# How to use hive with multiple users

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have several users use the same hive.

Now i want each user to have a private metadata in hive.

example:

user a call show table : a1 , a2, a3 ...

user b call show table : b1 , b2 ,b3 ...

Of course when user run query they can not access table of other user.

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

> In order to make setup easy for new users, Hive's Metastore is
>   configured to store metadata locally in an embedded Apache Derby
>   database. Unfortunately, this configuration only allows a single user
>   to access the Metastore at a time. Cloudera strongly encourages users
>   to use a MySQL database instead. This section describes how to
>   configure Hive to use a remote MySQL database, which allows Hive to
>   support multiple users. See the [Hive Metastore](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/AdminManual/MetastoreAdmin) documentation for
>   additional information.

For more details see the part with heading **'Configuring the Hive Metastore'** [here](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Hive+Installation).

Answer (score 3):

Once the external meta store has been [created](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/adminmanual-metastoreadmin.html) then [Hive authorization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization) can be used to grant/restrict privileges.

This is the [disclaimer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization) from Hive

> Hive authorization is not completely secure. In its current form, the authorization scheme is intended primarily to prevent good users from accidentally doing bad things, but makes no promises about preventing malicious users from doing malicious things.

Comment: looks like the Hive authorization doc moved to: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Authorization.  I edited your answer to resolve the broken link.